# Show an Page from Another Tenant SharePoint Online in Teams. I want to use custom iFrame. Is it possible by authenticating the user

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

I am currently working on an SPFX Teams webpart and show custom SharePoint online document library views in Teams. I have created an iframe in webpart and able to show this.
However when the app is deployed in other domain Tenent the iframe does not loads. The users from other domain tenant as added as guest users in SharePoint. Is there a way to authenticate them. iT is a Modern SharePoint site so cannot edit Master Page.

Comment: let me check this issue and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check that you have granted permissions to the guest users in your tenant? Check this [documenataion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview) for further information.

Comment: @Parmarth Kumar - Does your issue got resolved?